# How to determine if control center is dragged up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I'm creating an app that responds to up and down gesture recognizers.  I've noticed that when I accidentally drag the control center up, my methods that respond to an up swipe/drag also get called.
I have a BOOL named recordCalled that is true when an up swipe is detected, if the BOOL is true when the app goes into resign, certain methods are suppose to get called that put the app in its default state.  The problem is that when I drag the control center up, I enter resign before  recordCalled becomes true.  Once I swipe down the control center, my app comes back to the active state.  How can I prevent any methods from firing while the app is in resign?

EDIT:I'm able to get around this issue by creating another BOOL that becomes TRUE when resign is called and all the proceeding methods require the BOOL to be false in order to proceed. Is there a better way of knowing when the control center is present?

1. When I drag up both the control center this method gets called first.  Since none of the parameters are true, nothing happens.

   ```
   -(void) appDidEnterResign:(NSNotification *)notification
   {
       if(viewIsUp || recordCalled)
       {
           [self.panedView.layer removeAllAnimations];
           viewIsUp = NO;
           waitingTrackToSave = NO;
           [self moveViewsDown];
           [self onlyStopRecorder];
       }
   }
   ```
2. This method gets called immediately after resign but I still haven't entered the Active state.

   ```
   - (IBAction)handleUpSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
   {

        recordCalled = YES; 
       [self beginRecord];

   }
   ```
3. Followed by the following which calls the animation block to move the view up:

   ```
   -(void) beginRecord
   {
       if(viewIsUp == NO)
       {

       [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{

           [self moveViewsUp];

       } completion:^(BOOL finished){

       }];
   }

   -(void) moveViewsUp
   {
       if(!viewIsUp)
       {
           self.panedView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.panedView.frame, 0, -274);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You'd be better to add your comment to the question rather than asking it here to avoid confusion.